# Como passar argumentos dinamicamente para uma chamada new?

Tags: javascript, parâmetros, construtor

Se eu tenho uma função JavaScript e quero chamá-la passando uma lista de argumentos, uso `apply`:

```
var x = f(1,2,3);
var x = f.apply(null, [1,2,3]);
```

Pela primeira vez, me deparei com um caso em que eu preciso chamar um **construtor** com uma lista de argumentos, e a primeira coisa que tentei (mesmo suspeitando que ia dar errado) foi simplesmente fazer o mesmo:

```
var x = new f(1,2,3);
var x = new f.apply(null, [1,2,3]);
```

E de fato não funcionou... Há algum meio de fazer isso? Tenho de criar vários objetos, num loop, e me vi forçado a fazer assim:

```
var x = new f(lista[0], lista[1], lista[2]);
```

Que não é tão ruim no caso de um construtor com apenas 3 parâmetros, mas me pergunto se não existe um meio mais conciso ou "elegante".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No SOen há uma [resposta interessante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/2256325) com esta solução:

```
function construtor(Construtor) {
    return new (Construtor.bind.apply(Construtor, arguments));
}
```

Basicamente uma função que:

- muda indicador/escopo do `this` à Classe/Construtor que lhe é passada
- aplica-lhe os argumentos que lhe forem passados (não indicados na declaração da função porque são opcionais)
- retorna `new` desse construtor.

Um exemplo seria:

```
var Pessoa = function (nome) {
    this.nome = nome || 'Anónimo';
    this.getNome = function () {
        return this.nome;
    }
}

var Ana = new Pessoa('Ana');
console.log(Ana.getNome()); // "Ana"

function construtor(Construtor) {
    return new (Construtor.bind.apply(Construtor, arguments));
}

var Pedro = construtor(Pessoa, 'Pedro');
console.log(Pedro.getNome()); // "Pedro"

var Maria = construtor(Pessoa, 'Maria');
console.log(Maria.getNome()); // "Maria"
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/60snrx9L/

---

#### Nota:

Quando usamos `construtor` internamente ele faz `Classe.bind.apply(Classe, argumentos)`, o que quer dizer que o `.bind` vai ser chamado com contexto `Classe` e com argumentos da variável `argumentos`. Uma vez que o `.bind` consome o primeiro argumento como o contexto da função que fica "binded", esse primeiro elemento da array `argumentos` é descartado uma vez que o `new` cria um novo contexto.

Outra maneira, sem ter elementos descartaveis no `arguments` pode ser assim:

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
    function F() {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new F();
}
```

Comment: Interessante! Só que dessa forma eu teria que fazer `construtor.apply(null, [f].concat(lista))`. Mas nada que um pequeno ajuste não resolva: `function construtor(Construtor, args) { return new (Construtor.bind.apply(Construtor, [null].concat(args))); }` e para usar `construtor(f, lista)`. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/60snrx9L/1/)

Comment: @mgibsonbr bom ajuste. O `.unshift()` também daria(http://jsfiddle.net/60snrx9L/2/) mas a tua versão usa menos caracteres :)

Comment: O problema do `unshift` é que ele causa um efeito colateral na lista passada como argumento, enquanto o `concat` está sendo usado numa nova lista.

Comment: @mgibsonbr verdade, bem visto.